# Android studio layout xml not updating

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am using `Android Studio` latest version and recently facing a problem that, my layout xml `Design` view **not getting updated rapidly** if I have changed `background from selector` resource or changed the `image resource background`. I found that `Rebuild Project` again updating the layout. But my project is little big and its taking some time to rebuild again. It would be nice if there is any other quick solution for this. I have also tried the Synchronize xml option, but not worked as expected. Please suggest me if there is any better option. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

If problem persist just follow these steps:

**File> Invalid cache/Restart > Invalidate and Restart**

It will then surely work.

Comment: This solves it for me but it was short lived. The issue started again minutes later.

Comment: This is the only thing that works for me. But for some reason I need to do it after changing any of the code of my custom view - simply rebuilding the project, forcing layout refresh or changing the preview device doesn't do anything.

Comment: It is not an option. If you have a huge project rebuilding will take much time

Comment: I need to do it every time I add a new layout or else I have compile time error. why?

Comment: See my answer at the last comment if not superseded by new answers.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure when they added this but you can force the layout to refresh in the Design/Blueprint toggle menu (see below). This fixed the issue for me.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue. Mine ended up being caused by a duplicate layout file (in my case `res/layout/activity_main.xml` and `res/layout-v21/activity_main.xml`).

Turns out I enabled [alternative resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html?hl=de#AlternativeResources) for my layout, which created a copy of the layout for older API levels.

Reverting that change fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was also struck in the same problem and the Temporary and working solution is to change the preview device. If you want you can also switch to the previous device. Layout will be updated.

Sorry for being Late

Answer (score 1):

uncheck "Skip installation if APK has not changed":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess changing the tabs will refresh the layout. Try this. Hope this helps.

Comment: If u are meant switch the `Text/Design` tabs or switch the `xml layout` tabs, then its both are not worked.

Answer (score 0):

one time colse that file and open it again may be its reflected your changes if its not work than one time run your app and after changes of of your xml file its reflected in preview.

Comment: The OP does not specifically want to rebuild and run their app for the changes to show up.

Comment: than its problem with rendering in XML file layout.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by deleting the file ".flat" that matching the name of the xml file (for example, "activity_main.xml.flat").

Comment: how did it happen that your file got '.flat' at the end?

Comment: "These files that end with the .flat extension, are basically intermediate binary files which are created from the raw resource files of the android app that you are developing." https://www.techrbun.com/flat-file-extension/

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the build folder then rename the project folder of your app to something else.

I had a similar problem when running/debugging one of my apps on my Samsung Galaxy M31 after updating a TextView on an xml layout on one of my apps. I misspelled the attribute "android:color" not noticing until after running my app and got an error linking resources because of the misspelled "android:colo" that was not found. I tried deleting the project's build folder and doing File> Invalid caches > Invalidate and Restart and checked the "Clear file system cache and local history" checkbox but still got the problem. When I change the folder/directory name of my project after deleting the build folder, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

i added a LOTTIE Animation in my layout, and then this problem started. And this problem started after setting lottie animation from URL. I solved my problem by changing the Lottie from URL to Lottie from RawResourseFile. Actually this problem occurs due to bcoz, some of your layout attribute value is in wrong format, than is stopping to refresh layout automatically.